# Error al generar mi PDF con PHP y Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, html2pdf

estoy intentando generar un PDF de un registro en especifico pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulos\html2pdf_v4.01\html2pdf.class.php on line 2306
```

Este es mi botón para generar el PDF (se encuentra en el index.php)

```
<a href="pdf.php?refe=<?php echo $elid?>">Generar Reporte</a>
```

Y este es el código de pdf.php allí es donde me sale el error.

```
<?php
$pro=$_GET['refe'];
require("pdfconex.php");
require("html2pdf_v4.01/html2pdf.class.php");
$con=conectar();

$pdf=new HTML2PDF("L","Letter","es");

$sql="select * from trabajos where refe='$pro'";
$ok=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$producto=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ok);
```

Y mi conexión

```
<?php
function conectar(){
    return new mysqli("localhost","root","uzumy8.P","prueba");
}
$con = conectar();
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
       die("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8");
}
?>
```

Como podría solucionar ese error?

Muchas gracias cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad.

Saludos.

Comment: Te devuelve datos la consulta? Si es así, cómo manejas la data para exportar el pdf?

Comment: Hola @Bicho si me devuelve datos los mismos que llevo por medio de GET refe=94489480IM estoy usando la libreria Html2.PDF

Comment: Ya encontre el error muchas gracias @Bicho

Comment: Puedes agregar tu solución como respuesta, de esta manera si alguien tiene tu mismo problema le puede ser de mucha ayuda.